# Employee Complaining About Sister IT Group

Tags: conflict

I have an employee who is fed up with another business area that we rely upon to provide a sort of IT service to us. We should be able to do some things that this administration group does however our compliance construct does not allow this and the IT group is suffering from attrition so they must prioritize tasks like everyone else going through the Great Resignation. The employee came to me with a solution and that is to take over part of what he is asking them to do but I don’t control that group and that group is very much about retaining their current roles and no handing over work to another group.

I fear this employee may leave because he is fed up and I don’t know how to help him. He complains multiple times daily over the last year to where it’s not constructive anymore.

How can I convince him to just accept the situation if no one is willing to fix it ?

Comment: Why is nobody willing to fix it? Are the concerns not valid?

Comment: @Gregory Currie: Valid, but bureaucracy and politics at play here

Comment: Anything stopping you from just duplicating the work the other group is doing, without their consent?

Comment: @nick012000: Yes they hold all the keys. We don’t own the servers and can’t install anything (need root).

Comment: @Engineer2021 And you can't start your own servers rather than relying on theirs?

Comment: @nick01200: Nope

Comment: What is your role? How much power do you have to fix things?

Comment: @Engineer2021 Why not? Is it part of a contract or due to lack of resources?

Comment: @Helena: Team Lead, I am below two other directors. One in charge of my group and one in charge of that one. My director agrees but can’t get the other to change. We are stuck

Comment: "The employee came to me with a solution and that is to take over part of what he is asking them to do but I don’t control" What is this solution? Because sometimes, it's better to ask for forgiveness than permission.

Comment: @ComicSansSeraphim I don't want to put words in their mouth but I'd assume the IT infrastructure engineering is set up such that no one group can set up a service all on their own, they need to reserve server space, get firewalls configured, and so on, and the management approval for it is verified by a disinterested security group.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: Get out of the way of the solution and support your employee to fix a broken situation.

You didn't write what your position is, but going by the fact that you have an engineer seemingly reporting to you, I assume you are the first line of management, like a team lead or engineering manager.

> The employee came to me with a solution and that is to take over part of what he is asking them to do but I don’t control that group and that group is very much about retaining their current roles and no handing over work to another group.

What this sounds like is that the situation currently is very broken and you have a team member coming with a reasonable fix and you just turn them down because you don't know how to do it.
If you turn down good ideas, for no apparent reason other than you don't want to follow up on it, then this will be very demotivating.

You write you "don't control that group", but that is not the only way to achieve that outcome:

- talk to the other group about the impact them not meeting their commitments has
- escalate to your manager the situation and that you are wasting time and energy
- indicate that you and your employee are willing to help, by taking over responsibility or borrowing a head count to the new team.

You might not have the time to properly drive this initiative. In that case you need to get out of the way and allow the employee try to push this initiative.
Let them initiate meetings with the other group, let then write down the proposal, so you can share it with your manager an discuss the progress on this initiative with him.
Even if this still will not result in the changes your team member is suggested, they will feel taken seriously and see the world a little bit more from your shoes.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I convince him to just accept the situation if no one is
> willing to fix it ?

I'll assume that you have concluded (and you are correct) that the situation cannot be changed by you or your group.

In that case, something has convinced you to accept the situation. Perhaps you've been there long enough to understand how things actually work. Perhaps you've already tried to change things and failed. Perhaps you've been specifically told from above that this change is not possible.

Explain your thinking to the employee. Explain why you have chosen to accept an unfortunate situation. Perhaps they will be satisfied. Perhaps not.

Sometimes just leaving is the better solution for someone who is constantly complaining. Not every situation is a good fit.

Answer (score 2):

#### Offer them all a pay raise.

It sounds like there's a serious problem that your company isn't willing to fix for ridiculous reasons, so if you want to prevent attrition, there's really only one thing to do: create an incentive for them to stay.

That is, give them all generous pay raises, to make it worth dealing with your company's moronic policies.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere The issue is turnover; a pay raise would reduce turnover.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere A raise might prevent or delay them quitting.